# iPhone X specific UI API design changes required to be 100% compatible

Tags: ios, iphone

With the new iPhone X coming, are there any UI or UI Api changes required to fully support the iPhone X?

Are there any API changes that might affect the UIStatusBarStyle / UINavigationBar / UINavigationItem / UITabBar etc.

The only significant change I see is the larger display of 145pt longer.

The only information I could find is the Apple: Human Interface Guidelines
located here: 
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/

Comment: Have you looked at this https://developer.apple.com/ios/update-apps-for-iphone-x/

Comment: I like this guy's design for dealing with the top notch area : [Top Notch](https://twitter.com/vojtastavik/status/907911237983449088)

Answer (score 0):

For native IOS app the support is already given and all the info is available on full screen(18:9). Lots of app instead still need to fully support the new format so info available on 16:9 ratio

Answer (score 0):

In order to get full-screen applications you will need to recompile your apps with IOS 11 / Xcode 9.

If you use Standard UI controls you should be safe. If you use Autolayout you can utilise the new "[safeAreaLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area)" which will then basically help your ui design to respect the iPhoneX view port.

I found this Transcript from Apple located here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017-801/?time=126

"On iPhone X, people access the app switcher (indicated by the red arrow) and the Home screen by swiping up anywhere along the bottom edge of the display. An indicator at the bottom of the screen offers a hint about this interaction.
This indicator is displayed over your app's interface. You'll need to account for this when designing your app. If your app uses UIKit controls and auto-layout, designing and developing for iPhone X and our other devices should be straightforward. Standard UIKit elements such as navigation bars, tables, and collection views, automatically adjust when viewed on iPhone X. Navigation bars, tab bars, and toolbars are positioned and scaled appropriately on all iOS devices. The navigation bar's background material is extended to the display's top edge, and the background material of the tab bar and toolbar is extended to the bottom, while the elements they contain are positioned to prevent underlapping or clipping by other elements."

**Basically if you use standard UIKit you have nothing to worry about.**

Although Apple recommends: *"Make sure that your UI displays correctly and no elements are mispositioned, overlapping, incorrectly scaled, or clipped"*

*If you discover issues, use the safe area guides and layout margins to correctly position UI elements.*

[image]